# Is there ItemsPanelTemplate that will make the Items uniformly fill the control?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a ItemsControl and I will like the items to uniformly fill the the control.
Using a StackPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate only stretches in one direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want is a `Panel` that uniformly fills. Try the `UniformGrid` panel:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```